Editorial Manager submission breaking references
Someone else's probably asked this before, but I've been searching around to no avail for a specific solution to this problem.
I'm submitting to the Brain Stimulation journal, which uses the Editorial Manager interface. The PDF is generating fine, and everything except the references is working correctly.

The bibliographic information is loaded into the document like this:
\bibliography{refs}
originally I used \addbibresource
Both of these work fine in Overleaf with the references appearing as desired.
The result in Editorial Manager however looks like this:

and the references list is totally empty.
I've been tearing my hair out trying to fix this and nobody in my lab is quite sure how to fix it, as it's all compiling fine without errors/warnings in Overleaf.
I'd greatly appreciate any help here.
I've also tried embedding the references directly in the main .tex file, again - works on Overleaf, but does not work on the Editorial manager PDF builder.

" \addbibresource": Are you using biblatex? It is not supported by all journals. Check with your journal if they support it.

That will be the problem... I'll convert it to bibtex, if I can figure out how. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Talk to your journal. They will probably have an example how they want the references to be added.

This seems to be a problem with the submission system not a LaTeX problem. Note, that in this case it would be off-topic. A question on how to adapt concrete code (which would then also have to be shown) to concrete requirements (which would then also have to be named), on the other hand, would generally be appropriate.

It may work if you upload the generated files from biber so they don't need to run it so upload .bbl etc then latex will input them as normal tex files and biber doesn't need to run
